# HQL where clause query

Tags: hql

I have data, and I am trying to find out if data from one column affects data in another column. I can't put my real data up but an example is:

```
A 12345
A 23456
A 34567
A 45678
A 56789
B 12345
B 23456
B 34567
B 45678
B 56789
```

What I am trying to do is find where the data in column B (numbers) appears more than once in Column A (A or B).

I have roughly:

`select * 
from database 
where number < 56790 
and > 12344 
and COLUMN A ('A;, 'B');`

I have tried many variations of the Where clause but cant seem to get it sorted. Any ideas?

I am new to coding so sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find an answer.
Thanks in advance

I have the select and from sections ok in my query, its just this one bit I cant get.

Comment: Please include the query.

Comment: in the section I don't have any ideas that have worked. I have roughly:   select * from database where number < 56790 and > 12344 and COLUMN A ('A;, 'B');  but I cant get it to work to tell me where its in both a and b. I have researched this and checked loads of sites and cant get it. Hope that makes sense